# Creating a ec2 server instance with the name tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, coldfusion, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

Our project creates aws ec2 virtual server using `com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.RunInstancesRequest` from the aws java sdk. For now, to give a name to each instance, we sleep for 5 seconds and then create a `com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.Tag` to apply using a `com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.CreateTagsRequest`.

It works, most of the time. Sometimes we have servers without names and need to recreate them manually. I've been looking at the documentation but couldn't find a straightfoward way to give the server a name directly in the `runInstances` request.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass [tagSpecifications](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/model/RunInstancesRequest.Builder.html#tagSpecifications-java.util.Collection-) to the run instances request.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed the ressource type for the `tagSpecification` is "instance" in this case?